# How to send the selected visual block in ex command line?

Tags: vim, stdin, ex

I want to send a visual block as a stand-in for a command, such as

`:!echo < something from the visual block`

How could I do this in vim?

Comment: you want `something from the visual block` or `the whole visual block`?

Comment: @Kent The whole visual block. I want to send the text as standard input to what I selected to the underlying system commands.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is to `y`ank the visual selection (while in visual mode) into a register, and then start the command (`:!echo ...`) and insert the register's contents on the command-line via `<C-R>"`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [Command-line window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-window) via `q:`, as shown in this screen capture:

[image]